# Effect of centering on full rank matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

We consider three real symmetric square matrices $A,B, C$ of size $n$ where $A,B$ are positive-definite and full rank. It is clear that generally we cannot ensure that $\operatorname{ran}(AC) = \operatorname{ran}(BC)$.

However if $C = I - n^{-1}1_n$ where $1_n$ is the square matrix of size $n$ full of $1$'s, i.e. $C$ is the centering matrix, is it true that $\operatorname{ran}(AC) = \operatorname{ran}(BC)$?

I tried to prove it using the decomposition of $A = UDU^T$ and $B=VLV^T$ where $D$ and $L$ are diagonal matrices with positive entries on the diagonal and $U,V$ are orthogonal matrices but could not reach a satisfying conclusion.

Notation: for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n},$ $\operatorname{ran}(A) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid y = Ax, x \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are positive definite (or more generally, if $A,B$ are invertible), then it **always** holds that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(AC)$

Comment: $\operatorname{ran}$ is the image/range not the rank, sorry for the confusion, I edited my post.

Comment: My mistake, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We note that
$$
\operatorname{ran}(AC) = \operatorname{ran}(BC) \iff\\
\ker([AC]^\top) = \ker([BC]^\top) \iff\\
\ker(CA) = \ker(CB).
$$
Because $A$ is invertible, we have
$$
\ker(CA) = A^{-1} \cdot \ker(C) = \{A^{-1}x : x \in \ker(C)\}
$$
and a similar characterization of $\ker(CB)$. However, $\ker(C)$ is simply the span of $1_n$. So, these two kernels are equal if and only if the spans of (the necessarily non-zero vectors) $A^{-1}1_n$ and $B^{-1}1_n$ are the same, which is to say that $B^{-1}1_n$ is a multiple of $A^{-1}1_n$.